# Reduce the size of redstone circuit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm looking to reduce the size of a redstone circuit as much as possible, but my redstone skills aren't that great.

Would someone be able to offer some advise?

Currently I have the following circuit

[image: existing circuit]

What I'm actually trying to achieve is as follows. I'm trying to have an output that is steadily on, except for 3 ticks (approx) every minute, where it switches off. It's to help me build a auto brewer, but a little different to what I've already found on youtube.

Explanation of what I've done.

- Part 1 is a hopper clock, which will give me an output that transitions from off to on, every 60 seconds.
- Part 2 converts the signal transition from off to on, into a short pulse.
- Part 3 extends the short pulse into a 3 tick (approx) pulse.
- Part 4 simply inverts the signal so it's always on, apart from the 3 tick window.

The output is powering a hopper below my brewing stand, so that it can allow the brewed potions to enter the hopper.

I'm happy for the circuit to extend upwards, if I can reduce the overall footprint.

Any advise (or solutions) welcome.

Answer (score 3):

this is not complete but here are a few hints:

- you can put the timer under the pulse former by putting a floor over it and putting redstone on the block where the redstone block is under and avoiding the other one
- you can combine the pulse former and pulse extender into a single circuit by extending the delay of the repeater (combining several if needed)

  the pulse former works because the pulse is formed when the repeater is still delaying the signal while the comparer already has it
- the torch can be on top of the block reducing it's size by 1  and moving the signal up
- if you invert the signal on the side of the comparator the output will be inverted (always on with a off pulse)

Comment: Although your answer is good, it would make your answer much clearer if you posted screenshots of the changes you suggested.